# What would be the most efficient way of finding the first repeated term in Sylvester's sequence modulo the $n$th prime?

Tags: number-theory, integer-sequence

If a multiple of a prime, say 13, occurs in Sylvester's sequence, then Sylvester's sequence modulo that prime eventually gets stuck on a bunch of 1's, and `FixedPoint` would catch that: 2, 3, 7, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, ... But with 5, which is 2, 3, over and over again, `FixedPoint` would get the system stuck on an infinite loop, right?

So how do you catch that first repeated term if the sequence enters a period of length greater than 1?

More info about Sylvester's sequence: https://oeis.org/A000058, https://oeis.org/A256147.

Comment: It suffices to keep track of what values have been hit. When computing a_n (which should really be defined here, not in a link), check whether it has been hit already. if so, you are headed for repeats.

Comment: Maybe you can use four-argument form of  [NestWhile](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhile.html)?

Comment: @kguler Something like `NestWhile[Mod[#^2 - # + 1, Prime[n]], 2, MemberQ[#, I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT WOULD GO IN THIS SPOT], All]`?

Answer (score 5):

This is about as efficient as it gets (as D.L. said, just track seen values):

```
(* sequence generator *)
ClearAll[ss]
ss[0] = 2;
ss[n_] := ss[n] = ss[n - 1]^2 - ss[n - 1] + 1;

(* repeat finder *)
ssrep[mod_] := Module[{t, res, idx = 0},
  t[_] = True;
  While[t[res = Mod[ss[idx++], mod]], t[res] = False];
  {idx - 1, res}];

ssrep[Prime[#]] & /@ Range@10

(* {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {6, 1}, {7, 4}, {4, 2}, {7, 7}, {8, 3}} *)
```

Returns sequence index and value (Mod the argument - e.g., the second entries above of 1,1,2,1,3,1,4,2,7,3 are OEIS A256147 for the first ten primes)...

Be prepared for long running times / overflow / memory pressure...

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood so please correct me:

```
f = #^2 - # + 1 &;
s[n_] := Nest[f, 2, n - 1];
nf[n_] := 
 With[{lst = NestWhileList[Mod[f@#, n] &, 2, UnsameQ, All]}, 
  Last@lst -> 
   Grid[({Subscript["e", #], s@#} & /@ 
      Flatten@Position[lst, Last@lst]), Frame -> All]]
pnf[num_] := nf[Prime[num]]
```

So, looking at first ten primes:

```
Grid[Prepend[
  Table[{j, Prime[j], pnf[j]}, {j, 10}], {"n", "Prime[n]", 
   "Mod[\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(j\)]\),Prime[n]]->First \
consectuive Sylvester numbers same modulo Prime[n]"}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]